# Key sequence to automatically make math-mode fragments in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings, latex, math

My hands are getting lazier every day. Is there a key sequence to automatically type `\(_\)`, where `_` just denotes the position of my cursor, when I'm in org-mode? (Or `\[_\]`, of course: same question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a yasnippet for this:

```
# -*- mode: snippet; require-final-newline: nil -*-
# name: math for Org
# key: $$
# binding: direct-keybinding
# --
\\($1\\) $0
```

I type `$$` and get what you want: `\(_\)`.